# Cannot find error in iptables firewall configuration

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, iptables, firewall

I'm struggling with a firewall problem on my Centos server.

I have the following configuration which when I use it with a service iptables restart and I try to ssh to the server with putty, I cannot access the server - I just get a connection timeout error.

However when I leave the final REJECT line out I can.

I've opened the ports for ssh ie port 22. What am I doing wrong? Am I making a noobie mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:9090]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:372]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10050 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10051 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10051 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10050 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22   -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" ssh port\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25   -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" email\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53   -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" DNS large queries\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 53   -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" DNS small queries\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80   -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" Apache\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 110  -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" POP3\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443  -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" Apache ssl\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 953  -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" DNS Internal\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 993  -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" imaps\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" Squid\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" MySQL\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" Jenkins\"
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9090 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment  \" Pmta\"

-A INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP -m comment --comment \"IPSET drop ips on blacklist\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j SET --add-set blacklist src

-A INPUT -i ${PREFIX} -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP                 -m comment --comment \"Deny all null packets\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP                  -m comment --comment \"Deny all recon packets\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN -j DROP                  -m comment --comment \"nmap FIN stealth scan\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP          -m comment --comment \"SYN + FIN\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP          -m comment --comment \"SYN + RST\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP          -m comment --comment \"FIN + RST\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP          -m comment --comment \"FIN + URG + PSH\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL URG,ACK,PSH,RST,SYN,FIN -j DROP -m comment --comment \"XMAS\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP              -m comment --comment \"FIN without ACK\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP              -m comment --comment \"PSH without ACK\"
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP              -m comment --comment \"URG without ACK\"
-A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP         -m comment --comment \"Deny SYN flood attack\"
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment \"Accept traffic with ESTABLISHED flag set (limit - DDoS prevent)\"
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT   -m comment --comment \"Accept traffic with RELATED flag set (limit - DDoS prevent)\"
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP                    -m comment --comment \"Deny traffic with the INVALID flag set\"

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 30/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment \"Protection DDoS attacks\"

-A INPUT -j REJECT                               -m comment --comment \"Close up firewall. All else blocked.\"

COMMIT
```

Comment: you are using the NEW statement in your iptables rules, but you are missing the first rules for this "iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the recent module to dynamically maintain a list of IP addresses for each connection attemp to port 22 and refuse IPs trying to connect more than 4 times in a minute or using changing TTLs (note: this last check could cause trouble to legitimate connections too in some cases).

However, you are doing it wrong because you are not adding them anywhere to a list using a former rule holding a `--set` option. So your rule using the `--update` target returns false everytime since you are testing against an empty list called `SSH` and packets get dropped eventually by your last rule, thus the  last `ACK` packet of the three way handshake is dropped by the server.

You are looking for something like this instead :

```
-A INPUT -m recent --update --name SSH --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 --rttl -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i <iface> -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
```

This should be the only rules related to SSH, and parsed in this order by iptables when finding a match  (i.e. remove the rule with comment "ssh port" and make sure the order is respected).

Also a global note, you are trying to reject common TCP attack patterns but you do it after a lot of rules. You should move this on top : it means useless testing before actually dropping packets. Create custom chains for clarity if needed.

Comment: anyway, the rules order for iptables is wrong, you need to use first the rules with recent module and after the ssh accept normale rule.

Comment: @c4f4t0r That's what I'm explaining here.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer Xavier - I assume <iface> is something like eth0?

Comment: @Del Yes, exactly.